# How to add more attributes to Openfire MySQL database?

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I setup a Openfire server with external MySQL database using the openfire_mysql.sql file from the openfire installation directory to populate the database, the connection and everything basic seems to be ok.

However I need to add another attribute of a User instead of just "name", "email", I need to add "phone" and a long text field for users to save some notes.

Actually using the Smack API there are already enough attributes that can be stored in a User's data based on the API doc:

http://docs.jivesoftware.com/smack/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/AccountManager.html#getAccountAttributes()

However when doing createAccount with the parameter of Map attributes, the attribute is not persisted because I think the default database does not have fields to store this. So I used external database, yet still I can't see in the phpMyAdmin which fields this attribute get stored?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The solution to your problem would be saved in the vCard data from the user. Each user has a Vcard and it can be added all the data you need.

Comment: But is it possible to search for data from the vCard?

Comment: @miho did you found a solution about searching vCard data

Comment: @Ares91 No, I'm sorry.