# Openfire help. Custom database (tables,fields)

Tags: mysql, xmpp, openfire

I created a database for my chat application, which has, for example, more fields on the "user" table. How can I implement it in openfire?

I've already connected openfire to a mysql external database on my server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with [vCard](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0054.html)?

Surely if you connect your Openfire instance with an [LDAP](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ldap-guide.html) server you can retrieve other user fields (Organization unit, phone number, ...) using vCard.

Maybe this approach could work also for custom database integrated in Openfire; check also this posts which seem to suggest so:

[How to add more attributes to Openfire MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240979/how-to-add-more-attributes-to-openfire-mysql-database/7673814#7673814)

[Refreshing VCards in OpenFire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097041/refreshing-vcards-in-openfire/11363794#11363794)