# How can i save vcard information into openfire database using php library

Tags: php, web-services, xampp, openfire

I am using openfire for messaging system ( as admin console ) in mobile application. I need to add user's extra fields into openfire database.

I have searched and found that i can do that using vcard from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35218175

My question is how can i save user's additional fields into users database by vcard using php webservice. I also want to retrive those fields when retriving user but i need to do that using php webservice.

thank you for any kind of help and guidance